# Blocking mixed IPv6 formatting in System.Net.IPAddress class

Tags: c#, .net, ip, ipv6

I was searching an answer but I can't find it.
 I am using something like this

```
            if (IPAddress.TryParse(val, out parsedOutput))
            {    
                // ip address
                parsedOk = true;
            }
```

I am passing as val a string which looks like this: `0:0:0:0:0:0:1111:0`

I am getting in parsedOutput this: `::17.17.0.0`

Is there any way to get something like this: `::1111:0` instead of this "mixed" ipv4/ipv6 value?

Comment: Congrats! You may have found a bug in .NET! I have been researching this one and have found nothing as of yet.

Comment: I know this one may be against common programming standards, but have you tried to make a `TryParse` method that would give you what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation is actually correct according to [RFC 5952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952) (A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation). In [section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-5) it says:

> Addresses such as IPv4-Mapped IPv6 addresses, ISATAP
> [[RFC5214](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5214)], and IPv4-translatable
> addresses
> [[ADDR-FORMAT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#ref-ADDR-FORMAT)]
> have IPv4 addresses embedded in the low-order 32 bits of the address.
> These addresses have a special representation that may mix hexadecimal
> and dot decimal notations.  The decimal notation may be used only for
> the last 32 bits of the address.  For these addresses, mixed notation
> is RECOMMENDED if the following condition is met: the address can be
> distinguished as having IPv4 addresses embedded in the lower 32 bits
> solely from the address field through the use of a well-known prefix.
> Such prefixes are defined in
> [[RFC4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291)] and
> [[RFC2765](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2765)] at the time of this
> writing.

The IPv6 address you show is an IPv4-Compatible IPv6 Address. Its use is now deprecated, but it is still an IPv6 Address with Embedded IPv4 Addresses according to [RFC 4291 section 2.5.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.5). The parsed output is therefore correct and recommended.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is allowed, but thanks for a comprehensive answer

Comment: It is more than allowed: it's the recommended text representation :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: It's the string you are trying to parse. IPv6 addresses must have something in the first portion of the address, so if you were to throw in something like 2000 in there like this: `2000:0:0:0:0:0:1111:0` it will parse it correctly. It has to do with the way IPv6 address are understood by the computer.

Comment: Sorry but loopback Ipv6 address looks like this ::1 so it starts with only zeroes

Comment: So I will clarify, according to IPv6 spec, you don't have to have anything other than zeroes in there, but that's a reserved address. However, and this is important, the IP parser will automatically create an IPv4 address if you input **any byte, short or int** because of precisely the reason SanderSteffann mentioned. In order for the parser to create the correct address, you must force the value be greater than `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: but i am passing Ipv6 format string and I would like to get Ipv6 format value, simple. I don't wan't to have a mix, and this is a mix: "::17.17.0.0" i am not getting Ipv4, i am getting Ipv6 mixed with Ipv4 and I know that this is allowed but I would like to get clear Ipv6 value, which is allowed too

Comment: I did a little more experimentation and research. The bytes from the address show that the address is indeed a v6 address, so if you want the `ToString` output to be in the v6 format, you are most likely going to need to write one yourself.